# Plots on a calendar background, graphic interface, matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, background, calendar

I'm using matlab for a project. I have to get a similar result to this:
[image: Random image I found in google]

Is matlab suitable for this kind of plots?

Are there any software that could be more specific for this result?

Thank you

Comment: The answer is a good way to do it, the result was nice.

I used a similar structure because also with plots (not only with text) you can define the position. In particular I did it definig the position in the axes command. for r=1:X for c=1:Y ax = axes('Parent',fig,'Position',[sx(c) bo(r) b h]); plot... end end c=number of column r=number of row b=base of the single plot h=height of the single plot Where sx is the distance from the left border of the figure, function of the number of the column. Where bo is the distance from the bottom border of the figure, function of the number of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Matlab could do this, but it will require a lot of coding I think.

I would start with a function that draws the calender in a figure 
Then continue with filling the calender with the graphs and high and low values.

To find the first sunday before the start of the month you can use the start of this script. The rest draws a calender with day and date

```
month = [2011 04];% 2011 april
%month = [1987 02];% 1987 february (had exactly 4 weeks)
%month = [1983 01];% 1983 january  (requires 6 weeks to plot)
fig=figure(1);clf;hold on;axis image off
D = datenum([month,01]);
title(datestr(D,'mmmm yyyy'))
D=D-weekday(D)+1; %find sunday
square = [0,0;0,1;1,1;1,0;0,0]; %x and y to draw a square
row=1;
while row~=0
    for column = 1:7 %one week per row
        plot(square(:,1)+column-1,square(:,2)-row+1,'-k'); %go right each column, go down each row
        text(column-0.5,1.8-row,datestr(D,'ddd')); %name of day
        text(column-0.5,1.5-row,datestr(D,'DD'));  %number of day
        mp = mod(D-693961,29.530588853)./29.530588853; %crude approximation of lunar phase (693961 = 31-dec-1899)
        text(column-0.5,1.2-row,sprintf('%.2f',mp))
        D=D+1;
    end
    temp=datevec(D); %are we still in the right month?
    if temp(2)==month(2)
        row=row+1;  %new row
    else
        row=0; %stop the while loop
    end
end
```

Comment: It's very difficult because I should begin to draw the plot leaving the blank spaces in the beginning, to start from the right day... I'm trying with the function "subplot", minimizing the space between one plot and the other but it looks very hard

Comment: Yes. I would not use subplot for that. You always want to start on the last saturday of the previous month?

Comment: Mmm well this is up to me... I can "skip" the drawing of the plot until I place the first day at the corresponding day; in other words I left "blank" cells in the beginning if the first of the month is not Sunday (which is the first of the table). 
I can do that adding an array of NaN with the right dimension at the beginning of my X and Y axis.
But I have a huge doubt, how can go to a new line with a plot(after Saturday)?

Comment: Uh yes I studied it. It's close to what I need to do, but you use the text function. It is useful because with "text" you can define where to place the text within the figure. Is it possible to set the position (the beginning point) of a plot?
Anyway it was a detailed explanation, thank you very much.

Comment: I solved. I used a similar structure because also with plots (not only with text) you can define the position. In particular I did it definig the position in the axis command.

for r=1:X
for c=1:Y
 ax = axes('Parent',fig,'Position',[sx(c) bo(r) b h]);
plot...
end
end

c=number of column
r=number of row
b=base of the single plot
h=height of the single plot


Where sx is the distance from the left border of the figure, fuction of the number of the column.
Where bo is the distance from the bottom border of the figure, fuction of the number of the row.